# Why my ubuntu docker image does not have python?

Tags: python, docker

I have pull `amd64/ubuntu:18.04`
When I run the container and I am inside I do `python -V` and it says

```
bash: python: command not found
```

Why is this so? I thought ubuntu came with python installed

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: The environment we use at work uses this. I am aware of what you wrote and I am getting the necessary arguments to move our project to a supported release of ubuntu. But I need to understand this first.

Answer (score 4):

Python is not necessary to run a base image of Ubuntu.

You can always install python with

```
sudo apt install python3-all
```

In Ubuntu 20.04+, you can install the package `python-is-python3` to call `python3` with the command `python`.